# SpringBoot Jpa repository ignores delete query

Tags: java, hibernate, kotlin, jpa, spring-data-jpa

That is a very simple question i would like a simple answer

I've a database which among many other stuff has an entity column which can have many entities card

```
@Entity
@Table(
    name = "columns",
    uniqueConstraints = [
        javax.persistence.UniqueConstraint(columnNames = ["position", "board_id"])
    ]
)
class Column(
    groupId: Long,

    @ManyToOne(cascade = [CascadeType.DETACH], fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @field:JsonIgnore
    val board: Board,

    @Column(name = "title", insertable = true, updatable = true, unique = false, nullable = true, length = 128)
    @field:JsonProperty("title")
    var title: String,

    ) : GroupOwnedEntity(groupId) {
    constructor() : this(-1, Board(), "")

    @Column(name = "position", insertable = true, updatable = true, unique = false, nullable = false)
    @JsonProperty("position")
    @Min(0)
    var position: Int = 0

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = [CascadeType.ALL], orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "column")
    val cards: MutableList<Card> = ArrayList()

}
```

then card

```
@Entity
@Table(
    name = "cards",
    uniqueConstraints = [
        UniqueConstraint(columnNames = ["position", "column_id"])
    ]
)

class Card(
    groupId: Long,

    @ManyToOne(cascade = [CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.REMOVE], fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @field:JsonIgnore
    val column: br.com.fisgar.crm.entities.Column,

    @Column(name = "title", insertable = true, updatable = true, unique = false, nullable = true, length = 128)
    @field:JsonProperty("title")
    var title: String
) : GroupOwnedEntity(groupId) {
    constructor() : this(-1, br.com.fisgar.crm.entities.Column(), "")

    @Column(name = "position", insertable = true, updatable = true, unique = false, nullable = false)
    @JsonProperty("position")
    @Min(0)
    var position: Int = 0

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = [CascadeType.ALL], orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "card")
    val tasks: MutableList<Task> = ArrayList()


    @Column(name = "data")
    @JsonIgnore
    var data: String? = null

    @JsonProperty("data")
    fun data(): Map<String, Any>? {
        if (data == null) return emptyMap()

        val mapper = ObjectMapper()
        val typeRef: TypeReference<HashMap<String, Any>> = object : TypeReference<HashMap<String, Any>>() {}

        return mapper.readValue(data, typeRef)
    }
}
```

I'm trying to delete a card like this:

```
val column = columnService.create(board.id, InCreateColumnDto("column name"))
val card = cardService.create(column.id, InCreateCardDto("card name"))
cardService.delete(card.id)
```

using phpmyadmin i can see that the rows are being created, but the delete statement never gets executed

then i added the trace log to hibernate to see what variables are being bind to the query

```
2022-06-21 23:36:38.614 DEBUG 29908 --- [           main] org.hibernate.SQL                        : 
    delete 
    from
        cards 
    where
        id=?
2022-06-21 23:36:38.614 TRACE 29908 --- [           main] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - [24]
```

and 24 is exactly the id of the card in the database

then i wrote my own delete query on the jpa repository

```
@Repository
interface CardRepository : CrudRepository<Card, Long> {

      @Modifying
    @Query("DELETE FROM Card c where c.id = :id")
    override fun deleteById(@Param("id") id: Long)


}
```

same thing, entity created, method called, hibernate prints the query in the log, but nothing goes to the database...

I know that this is stubborn behavior from JPA because card is part of a bigger entity and I should be updating the big one... but i dont want to make a huge query just to delete 1 card

If 1 column has 20000 cards and everytime i decide to delete 1 card i need to query and load all 20000 cards just to update the column on repository... this is a absurd waste of resources...

does anyone know a way of forcing jpa to accept my delete since i do know the entity id?

Comment: Is the cardService.delete transactional?

Comment: yes it is `@Transactional
    fun delete(cardId: Long) {
         cardRepository.deleteById(cardId)
    }` where deleteById is default jparepository method [but if i do my own custom method happens the same

Comment: and you see in the logs that the transaction is committed?

Comment: how can i see that? i see in the logs hibernate printing the query.... i dont know how to check if the transaction is commited

Comment: set logging.level.org.springframework.transaction.interceptor=trace